# Can't start Hbase after Kerberos the Cluster(ERROR [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server )

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos, apache-zookeeper

I'm quite new to the Hadoop and Kerberos, and now I have a hadoop cluster with 5 machines(2 namenodes and 3 datanodes(Centos 7)), before I kerberosed the cluster, all functions runs well(hadoop,hbase,zookeeper....)and I just want to learn the Kerberos and I kerberosed the hadoop and zookeeper, it seems ok, and just after i setup the Hbase according to the http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_sg_hbase_authentication.html

my Hbase cannot start, the [ERROR INFO is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHqDO.png)
I've tried everything I could searched from Google, but nothing worked. 
Please HELP!

- part of my  hbase-site.xml

  ```
  <property> 
      <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
      <value>kerberos</value> 
  </property>  
  <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name> 
      <value>cdp/_HOST@XXXXXX.COM</value> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
      <name>hbase.regionserver.keytab.file</name> 
      <value>/opt/cdw/hbase-1.2.0-cdh5.7.3/conf/hadoop.keytab</value> 
  </property>

  <property> 
      <name>hbase.master.kerberos.principal</name> 
      <value>cdp/_HOST@XXXXXXXX.COM</value> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
      <name>hbase.master.keytab.file</name> 
      <value>/opt/cdw/hbase-1.2.0-cdh5.7.3/conf/hadoop.keytab</value> 
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
  ```
- my zk-jaas.conf

  ```
  Client {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=true
        useTicketCache=false
        keyTab="/opt/cdw/hbase-1.2.0-cdh5.7.3/conf/hadoop.keytab"
        principal="cdp/cdwdata1@XXXXXXX.COM";
  };
  ```
- I also add 2 lines into hbase-env.sh

  ```
  export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
  export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/cdw/hbase-1.2.0-cdh5.7.3/conf/zk-jaas.conf"
  ```
- I don't understand where did I miss
- BTW, I also sure of done the chmod and chown to directories and files
- Please Help, THX!!

Comment: Have you tried creating a **keytab** file and using it to authenticate your remote systems that use kerberos?

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar I'm sorry. What do you mean to authenticate my remote systems? I am trying to kerberos my cluster and I do have a key tab,  and I can access to my hdfs but the hbase can not start.

Comment: If what I guess is right, you need to authenticate and establish a connection with your kerberos HBase which I think is not happening.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar I have set the keytab directory in all hbase-site.xml, zk-jaas.conf and hbase-env.sh, so why the hbase can't start, I mean the start-hbase.sh failed and the process in namenode and datanode which should have Hmaster and Hregionserver do not appear. and how should I do towards your advice of establishing a connection with my kerberos Hbase(I am not sure of the settings are right), Thanks!

Comment: The usual way that I follow to establish a connection to kerberos HBase is by running `kinit` script manually on my edge node on the keytab file that contains the valid credentials. I'm not sure if that is how you should also be doing it.